ESLint custom rule to restrict Material UI imports
I'm working in a project that's in Nextjs 14 with Material UI 5 components for styling. I want to know if there's a ESLint custom rule to restrict the way of importing the components, probably with no-restricted-imports.
// This should trigger an error
import { Box } from "@material-ui/material";
// This should be allowed
import Box from "@material-ui/material/Button";

Is there a custom ESLint rule that would satisfy my needs instead that I can easily put into the rules section? Plugins that are not deprecated are also welcome.
I already tried various configs with no-restricted-imports but couldn't hack it. Maybe someone with more experience on ESLint can help me.

Have ou tried regex or patterns on the no-restricted-imports rule? Please share your attempts.

@Arkellys I have tried @mui/material but that restricts something like @mui/material/Box as well. Also tried !@mui/* but it doesn't work.

Just made it work using some propper regex:
"no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
    "patterns": [{
      "regex": "@material-ui\/material$",
      "message": "No root mui import"
}]


@material-ui\/material$ escape the forward slash and mark end of string using dollar sign $

playground
Edit: if you also want to block when it might have a slash in the end like: import { Box } from "@material-ui/material/" then use this expression @material-ui\/material\/{0,1}$

As an alternative to the approach shown by @vzsoares, you can use the paths option of the no-restricted-imports rule with a simple string value. That will do what you want by default.
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "paths": [
          {
            "name": "@material-ui/material",
            "message": "Your error message",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

